# Covering a graph by trees with depth constraint

Tags: graph-theory, np

Given a graph $G$ and a depth constraint $h$, my question is: what is the complexity to find a tree cover of $G$, denoted as $T=\{T_1, T_2, ..., T_n\}$. For each $T_i$, its depth(height) is no larger than $h$, and the union of all trees in $T$ covers $G$.
Is this problem an NP-complete problem or NP-hard? or it is the same problem with some existing ones?

Waiting for your answers, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to find a minimum covering.  If $h$ is part of the input, then this problem is indeed NP-hard.  For example, if $h=1$, then each tree is a star, and the problem reduces to computing a minimum vertex cover, which is NP-hard.  I believe it should be NP-hard for any fixed $h$ as well.

Comment: yes, when h=1, the problem is just to find a minimum vertex cover of a graph. but i really find it difficult to confirm the complexity when h > 1. i have not found an equal NP-hard prolbem of it yet. any suggestions? thank u..

Comment: @Tony, I think your *iff* is broken.  Consider the prism of a triangle.  Its min vertex cover has size 4 since each triangle needs at least 2.  However if you subdivide each edge with one more vertex, you can cover the new graph with 3 trees of depth 2.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay, Thanks!  You are right.  I edited that part out.  I still believe it is NP-hard for arbitrary $h$ though.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay Sorry, i dont quite understand the example you gave. can you make a more precise description? Thank you.

Comment: @Locker The triangular prism graph consists of two disjoint triangles joined by a matching.  As Brendan mentioned, it has vertex cover number 4, since you need 2 vertices to cover each triangle.  However, if you subdivide every edge of the triangular prism, it can actually be covered with 3 trees of depth 2.  Just take the 3 trees which are rooted at the subdivided vertices of the matching edges.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay Thanks! I totally understand now. But would you mind give me some further advices about the original question? Since I have found that it is different from many existing ones, such as k-path cover problem and k-cover trees.

Comment: How about replacing each edge by a path with $h - 1$ vertices?  I haven't checked the details, but it seems there should be a way to reduce from vertex cover again.